# Why do I have a 32 bit and 64 bit Excel?

Tags: microsoft-office, 32-vs-64-bit

I am using Windows 10 and have installed a 64 bit version of Office. I cannot for the best of my life remember having installed a 32 bit version as well. However, when I open the Start Menu, I find two Excel entries, one labeled just *Excel*, the other labeled *Excel 2016*.

When I open the *Excel* entry and use the VBA conditional compiler directive constants `Win32` and `Win64` to determine the bitness of Excel, I unexpectedly find that the Excel that I am running is a 32 Bit version. However, If I open the *Excel 2016* entry, and determine the bitness of Excel, this time, I find it to be 64 bit.

Furthermore, when I try to find out the executed exe with a right mouse click on either the *Excel* or *Excel 2016* entry, I am only presented with a *Open file location* on the *Excel 2016* entry. The *Excel* entry seems to be missing this option.

I am very confused what's going on here and would appreciate any help for clearing this up to me.

As per *harrymc's* request, the first three lines of *File > Account > About Excel* in the 32 bit version read

```
MicrosoftⓇ ExcelⓇ for Office 365 MSO (16.0.11727.20222) 32-bit
Product ID: 00338-91691-45894-AA859
Session ID: 81A6FBD9-F409-4AD9-ABDF-C441C271B6A3
```

those for the 64 bit version read

```
MicrosoftⓇ ExcelⓇ für Office 365 MSO (16.0.11727.20222) 64-Bit
Product ID: 00338-91691-45894-AA859
Sitzungs-ID: 10A62CF3-8C54-44A1-B26F-8074DC35812E
```

Comment: Could you for both Excel versions go into *File > Account > About Excel* and include the upper 3 lines in your post.

Answer (score 2):

From the information of “About Excel”, it seems you have installed Office 365 in two different languages. One is English version 32-bit and another is German version 64-bit.

You can verify this in “Control Panel” -> “Program and Features”, then maybe you will find two Office 365 application. Such as:

[image]

You can delete the redundant software by right click then choose “Uninstall”.